# Adding classes to active custom menu item WHMCS

Tags: php, menu, hook, whmcs

I am using a PayPal Billing gateway for WHMCS and have added the menu item to both the ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar and ClientAreaSecondarySidebar using the following in a hook file:

```
<?php 

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem; 

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar) { 
    if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing'))) { 
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')->addChild('Manage PayPal Billing', array( 
            'label' => 'Manage PayPal Billing', 
            'uri' => 'paypalbilling.php', 
            'order' => '30' 
        )); 
    } 
}); 

add_hook('ClientAreaSecondarySidebar', 1, function (MenuItem $secondarySidebar) { 
    if (!is_null($secondarySidebar->getChild('Billing'))) { 
        $secondarySidebar->getChild('Billing')->addChild('Manage PayPal Billing', array( 
            'label' => 'Manage PayPal Billing', 
            'uri' => 'paypalbilling.php', 
            'order' => '30' 
        )); 
    } 
});
```

I need to get the "Billing" menu item in `ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar` to have the class `open` when someone is on the paypalbilling.php page and also highlight the "Manage PayPal Billing" child item under "Billing" with the class `active`. Then I need to get the "Manage PayPal Billing" menu item in the `ClientAreaSecondarySidebar` to be highlighted also with the class `active`.
Obviously I only need to add the classes when this is the active page.

I have a feeling it might be to do with the core paypalbilling.php page not defining breadcrumbs.. but not certain. That custom page code is not open source, so I can't see it or edit it :(

I have tried using `setClass` in this hook in all different ways, but can't figure out the conditional for `if( is current page = paypalbilling.php )`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to add the classes to the sub menus using the current page, still can't add a class to the main `ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar` Billing menu.

I tried `$primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')->setClass('active');` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code for checking the current page and setting the new menu items with a class of "active":

```
<?php

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar) {

    $filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
    $parseFile = explode('.', $filename);

    if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing'))) {

        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')->addChild('Manage PayPal Billing', array(
            'label' => 'Manage PayPal Billing',
            'uri' => 'paypalbilling.php',
            'order' => '30'
        ));

        if ($parseFile['0']=='paypalbilling'){
            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')->setClass('active'); // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')->getChild('Manage PayPal Billing')->setClass('active');
        }

    }

});

add_hook('ClientAreaSecondarySidebar', 1, function (MenuItem $secondarySidebar) {

    $filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
    $parseFile = explode('.', $filename);

    if (!is_null($secondarySidebar->getChild('Billing'))) {

        $secondarySidebar->getChild('Billing')->addChild('Manage PayPal Billing', array(
            'label' => 'Manage PayPal Billing',
            'uri' => 'paypalbilling.php',
            'order' => '30'
        ));

        if ($parseFile['0']=='paypalbilling'){
            $secondarySidebar->getChild('Billing')->getChild('Manage PayPal Billing')->setClass('active');
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (from Documentation), WHMCS doesn't have any method for getting active state of the menu. I solve the problem using JavaScript. Hope it may help anyone.

```
const liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// Loop through each li element
liElements.forEach(liElement => {
    const anchorElement = liElement.querySelector('a');

    if (anchorElement && anchorElement.href === window.location.href) {
        liElement.classList.add('active');

        const dropdownParent = liElement.closest('.dropdown');
        if (dropdownParent) {
            dropdownParent.classList.add('active');
        }

        return;
    }

    const childLiElements = liElement.querySelectorAll('li');
    childLiElements.forEach(childLiElement => {
        const childAnchorElement = childLiElement.querySelector('a');

        if (childAnchorElement && childAnchorElement.href === window.location.href) {
            liElement.classList.add('active');

            const dropdownParent = liElement.closest('.dropdown');
            if (dropdownParent) {
                dropdownParent.classList.add('active');
            }

            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Another approach is to use PHP $_SERVER to implement the same URL based logic.